# Zipping two HashMaps

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have two HashMaps:

```
import Data.HashMap.Strict
m1 :: HashMap Char Int
m2 :: HashMap Char Int
??? :: (v1 -> v2 -> v3) -> HashMap k v1 -> HashMap k v2 -> HashMap k v3
-- or even
??? :: (k -> v1 -> v2 -> v3) -> HashMap k v1 -> HashMap k v2 -> HashMap k v3
```

I'd like some kind of `zip` to walk over these maps, where:

1. if a key exists in one map but not the other, it is substituted with a default (sort of **"zip longest"**)
2. the **result type can be different** from the original types.

This matches the signature of [`intersectionWithKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers/docs/Data-HashMap-Strict.html#v:intersectionWithKey) with semantics closer to [`unionWithKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers/docs/Data-HashMap-Strict.html#v:unionWithKey).

A concrete example: for a simple case of applying `(,)` with a 0 default, I can do

```
unionWith add (map (,0) m1) (map (0,) m2) :: HashMap Char (Int, Int)
add (a, x) (b, y) = (a+b, x+y)
```

This provokes the question: is there a clean way to do this in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

1. Merge the two maps to get a list of all keys
2. Define a new function that, given a key, uses `lookupDefault` to
   get the appropriate value (default or real) from each map in order
   to compute the value for the new map
3. Map that function over the keys, and create a new hash map from the result.

---

```
zipMap :: (v1 -> v2 -> v3) -- Combining function
       -> v1               -- default value for keys unique to the second map
       -> v2               -- default value for keys unique to the first map
       -> HashMap k v1
       -> HashMap k v2
       -> HashMap k v3
zipMap f d1 d2 m1 m2 = let allKeys = keys (union m1 m2)
                           f' k = (k, f (lookupDefault d1 k m1) (lookupDefault d2 k m2))
                       in fromList $ map f' allKeys
```

Comment: Yes; I though there was some function to do that, but completely overlooked it while skimming the docs for it.

Comment: One more thing though: `fromList` takes a `[(k, v)]`, and `f'` returns just a `v`. So `zipMap` has to either add the key or expect this from the user-supplied `f`. Can you please fix this (in either direction) in case someone else finds this useful? :)

Comment: Oh, right. I had it wrong in an earlier version, too; I fixed it there, but not here.

Answer (score 1):

The [these](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these) package provides the [`These`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.7.6/docs/Data-These.html#t:These) datatype, which is a bit like `Either` but has an extra constructor for when *both* cases are present.

The package also defines typeclasses for "zipping with padding" over data structures. In particular the [`Align`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.7.6/docs/Data-Align.html#t:Align) typeclass, which has a `HashMap` instance.

For example, to zip two maps using `0`s for missing entries:

```
import Data.These
import Data.Align

padWithZeros :: (Align f, Num a, Num b) => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
padWithZeros = alignWith (fromThese 0 0)
```

There are also [`Data.Align.Indexed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.7.6/docs/Data-Align-Indexed.html) and `Data.Align.Keyed`, which give the zipping function access to the key.

One disadvantage of [these](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these) is that the dependency foot print is somewhat heavy.

Comment: Wow, `These` looks very natural in this scenario. That's really cool, although obviously installing another package is not always convenient (dependency on aeson? wtf).

Comment: I can confirm that this works well, but in my case installing an extra library was not an option. Nevertheless, thank you for showing me `these`